# Download full data with DT in a module shiny app using external downloadbutton without using server = F

Tags: javascript, r, shiny, download, dt

In my shiny application, I want to give you the option of downloading complete data in **CSV**, **Excel** and **PDF** format. Ideally, a download button that breaks down into 3 buttons. I've seen on some threads that you can set the `server = FALSE` option, but I can't do that because my data is too big.

I've followed this issue: https://github.com/rstudio/DT/issues/267 with the comment from

> stla on May 6 2020.

However, when I try to reproduce his example it doesn't work. Idon't know if it comes from my module way

```
library(shiny)
library(shinyjs)
library(shinyWidgets)
library(datamods)


module1_ui <- function(id) {
  ns <- NS(id)
  
  tabPanel(
    title = "tab title",
    
    fluidRow(
      column(width = 3, 
             filter_data_ui(ns("filtering"))),
      column(width = 9, 
             downloadButton(ns("download1"), ""), # no label: this button will be hidden
             DT::DTOutput(outputId = ns("table"))
             )
      )
    )
}

module1_server <- function(id, r_global) {
  moduleServer(id, function(input, output, session) {
    ns <- session$ns
    
    row_filter_vars <- reactive({
      list(
        Sepal.Length = "Sepal.Length",
        Sepal.Width = "Sepal.Width",
        Petal.Length = "Petal.Length",
        Petal.Width = "Petal.Width",
        Species = "Species"
      )
    })
    
    data <- reactive({
      iris
    })
    
    res_filter <- filter_data_server(id = "filtering",
                                     data = data,
                                     vars = row_filter_vars)
    
    observeEvent(res_filter$filtered(), {
      updateProgressBar(
        session = session,
        id = "pbar",
        value = nrow(res_filter$filtered()),
        total = nrow(data())
      )
    })
    
    
    callback <- JS(
      "var a = document.createElement('a');",
      "$(a).addClass('dt-button');",
      "a.href = document.getElementById('download1').href;",
      "a.download = '';",
      "$(a).attr('target', '_blank');",
      "$(a).text('Download');",
      "$('div.dwnld').append(a);",
      "$('#download1').hide();"
    )
    
    output$table <- renderDT(
      datatable(
        data = res_filter$filtered(),
        callback = callback,
        extensions = 'Buttons',
        options = list(dom = 'B<"dwnld">frtip',
                       buttons = list())
      )
    )

   output$download1 <- downloadHandler(
      filename = function() {
        paste("data-", Sys.Date(), ".csv", sep="")
      },
      content = function(file) {
        write.csv(iris, file)
      }
    )
  })
}



#________________________________________________________________
#                          MAIN UI                           ----
#________________________________________________________________
app_ui <- function(request) {
  tagList(navbarPage(id = "main_menu", "My app",
                     module1_ui("mod1")))
}

#________________________________________________________________
#                        MAIN SERVER                         ----
#________________________________________________________________
app_server <- function(input, output, session) {
  r_global <- reactiveValues(data = NULL)
  
  module1_server(id = "mod1", r_global = r_global)
}


shinyApp(ui = app_ui, server = app_server)
```

EDIT :

I had this

```
 callback <- JS(
      "var a = document.createElement('a');",
      "$(a).addClass('dt-button');",
      sprintf("a.href = document.getElementById$('%s').href", ns("download1")),
      "a.download = '';",
      "$(a).attr('target', '_blank');",
      "$(a).text('DOWNLOAD');",
      "$('div.dwnld').append(a);",
      sprintf("$('#%s').hide();", ns("download1"))
    )
```

in the server module part but it still not display the label button (DOWNLOAD). It download the CSV file but it's not linked with the JS part

Comment: Hello, I am stla. You have to add the `ns` to `download1` in the JavaScript code. And where is the download handler?

Comment: Indeed, I forgot to put it on the example. I will try the NS in JS

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent how does it works to add ns in JS code ??

Comment: For example, replace `"$('#download1').hide();"` with `sprintf("$('#%s').hide();", ns("download1")`.

Comment: There's no `$` after `document.getElementById`.